# Google Visualization getSelection() not as expected

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I would like to access the state of the `dashboard` once a user has made a picker selection.

I've tried using `dashboard.getSelection()` but it returns nothing after a picker has been chosen.  The documentation appears to describe what I would like to accomplish.

> Returns an array of the selected visual entities of the charts in the
> dashboard. The getSelection() method, when called on the dashboard,
> returns an aggregate of all of the selections made on all of the
> charts within it, allowing for the use of a single reference when
> working with chart selections.

What am I missing?

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'table', 'gauge', 'controls', 'charteditor']
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  //console.log("ready!");
  renderChart_onPageLoad();
});

function renderChart_onPageLoad() {
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    //console.log("renderChart_onPageLoad");
    drawDashboard_A("A");
  });
}

function drawDashboard_A(suffix) {
  //console.log("drawDashboard");

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Name', 'RoolNumber', 'Gender', 'Age', 'DonutsEaten'],
    ['Michael', 1, 'Male', 12, 5],
    ['Elisa', 2, 'Female', 20, 7],
    ['Robert', 3, 'Male', 7, 3],
    ['John', 4, 'Male', 54, 2],
    ['Jessica', 5, 'Female', 22, 6],
    ['Aaron', 6, 'Male', 3, 1],
    ['Margareth', 7, 'Female', 42, 8],
    ['Miranda', 8, 'Female', 33, 6]
  ]);

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_' + suffix));

  var categoryPicker1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'categoryPicker1_' + suffix,
    options: {
      filterColumnLabel: 'Gender',
      ui: {
        labelStacking: 'vertical',
        allowTyping: false,
        allowMultiple: false
      }
    }
  });

  var categoryPicker2 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'categoryPicker2_' + suffix,
    options: {
      filterColumnLabel: 'RoolNumber',
      ui: {
        labelStacking: 'vertical',
        allowTyping: false,
        allowMultiple: false
      }
    }
  });

  var proxyTable = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'proxyTable_' + suffix,
    options: {
      width: '500px'
    }
  });

 

  //This json contains my settings for later
  let json = {
    "tableChart": {
      "hasTable": true,
      "dataView": {
        "columns": [{
            "id": "Name"
          },
          {
            "id": "RoolNumber"
          },
          {
            "id": "Gender"
          },
          {
            "id": "Age"
          },
          {
            "id": "DonutsEaten"
          }
        ]
      },
      "groupView": {
        "hasGroupView": false
      },
      "totalRow": {
        "hasTotalRow": true,
        "labelCol": "Total",
        "labelColIndex": 0, //This is the column where the words "Grand Total" are stored.  It must be text column.
        "totalColumns": [{
          "id": "RoolNumber",
          "type": "number",
          "function": "sum"
        }]
      },
      "conditionalFormat": {
        "hasConditionalFormat": false
      },
      "options": {},
      "hasCSV": false,
      "clickGetFunc": null
    },
  };

 
  google.visualization.events.addListener(proxyTable, 'ready', function() {
    console.log(suffix + ".addListener(proxyTable, 'ready' - picker state");

    //console.log('state proxy id', proxyTable.getContainerId());
    //console.log('state proxy table', proxyTable);
    console.log('state dashboard selection', dashboard.getSelection());
    console.log('state picker1 direct', categoryPicker1.getState()); //returns result for single picker
    console.log('state picker2 direct', categoryPicker2.getState()); //returns result for single picker

  });


  dashboard.bind([categoryPicker1, categoryPicker2], [proxyTable]);
  dashboard.draw(data);
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="dashboardA">
  <div id="categoryPicker1_A"></div><br />
  <div id="categoryPicker2_A"></div><br />
  <div id="proxyTable_A" style=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: the dashboard selection method only returns selections made on the charts, not the controls. and `table` is not included in the dashboard's bind method, only `proxyTable`.

Comment: Hi, I've simplified the snippet.  The dashboard now has two pickers and a table.  I'm a bit confused, since dashboard selection method only works on the included charts, how can I return an aggregate of the controls current state?

Comment: there's not a method that will do this for you. you could store the controls in an array or object, which would allow you to loop over them, and gather each state...

Comment: I ended up just doing just that.  Please see my answer post and let me know if this was a good way to accomplish the goal.  I still thank you because I used the `categoryPickerState[controlWrapper.getContainerId()]` and `.hasOwnProperty` you just introduced to me last week.

Comment: pity they don't provide a way to do this in aggregate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using an array to build the category pickers (which I normally do but don't post here for simplicity) using a function called `categoryPicker_default`.

```
var categoryPickerArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < categoryPickerColumns.length; i++) {
    categoryPickerArray.push(
        new google.visualization.ControlWrapper(categoryPicker_default(i)),
    );
};
```

Then binding to my dashboard in this way.

```
dashboard.bind(categoryPickerArray, [proxyTable]);
```

Then build the event listners dynamically based on the number of pickers in `categoryPickerArray`.

On `statechange` `lib_gcharts_categoryPickerState` is called to collect the update.

```
for (let i = 0; i < categoryPickerArray.length; i++) {
    google.visualization.events.addListener(categoryPickerArray[i], 'statechange', function () {            
        lib_gcharts_categoryPickerState(categoryPickerArray[i]);
    });
};
```

Then using `categoryPickerState` to collect the values after `statechange`.

```
var categoryPickerState = {};

function lib_gcharts_categoryPickerState(controlWrapper) {
    if (categoryPickerState.hasOwnProperty(controlWrapper.getContainerId())) {
        delete categoryPickerState[controlWrapper.getContainerId()];
    }
    categoryPickerState[controlWrapper.getContainerId()] = controlWrapper.getState();
}
```

Thank you to @WhiteHat for introducing this method of collecting values in a previous post.

Comment: Thank you very much for being there!